# Stop evaluating an built-in Mathematica function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to simplify some formulas like

```
F[a,b,c]*F[a,c,b]+F[c,a,b] /. {a->1,b->2,c->3}
```

where

```
F[a,b,c] := LegendreP[a,x]+LegendreP[b,x]*LegendreP[c,x]
```

And Mathematica can give a polynomial of x.

But I would like to keep all LegendreP instead of expanding it. By setting the `HoldAll` attribute of `LegendreP`, I can stop this, but the arguments are also kept, which is not intended.

Could anyone give some advice to solve this problem? Thanks.

Edited: I would like to have a result like this for the above formula (where `L=LegendreP`)

```
L[3,x]+L[1,x]*L[2,x]+L[1,x]*L[1,x]+L[3,x]*L[2,x]*L[1,x]+L[1,x]*L[2,x]*L[3,x]+L[‌​3,x]*L[2,x]*L[2,x]*L[3,x]
```

Answer (score 2):

> But I would like to keep all LegendreP instead of expanded it.

Can't you use HoldForm?

```
F[a_, b_, c_] := HoldForm[LegendreP[a, x] + LegendreP[b, x]*LegendreP[c, x]];
F[a, b, c]*F[a, c, b] + F[c, a, b] /. {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ReleaseHold[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Simplify[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Excuse me, but this is not what I am trying to do: I would like to have `L[3,x]+L[1,x]*L[2,x]+L[1,x]*L[1,x]+L[3,x]*L[2,x]*L[1,x]+L[1,x]*L[2,x]*L[3,x]+L[3,x]*L[2,x]*L[2,x]*L[3,x]`

Answer (score 1):

without knowing fully what you are trying to accomplish, one approach is to simply use some other symbol, eg:

```
 F[a,b,c] := legendreP[a,x]+legendreP[b,x]*legendreP[c,x]
```

(note the lower case "l" )

When you get to the stage where you want evaluation apply a pattern substitution:

```
 expr /. legendreP->LegendreP
```

Comment: The only drawback is that Mathematica won't know anything about legendreP so you might need to manually program a few properties of those polynomials that you want to use before making the final substitution proposed by the answerer.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, this is exactly what I am doing, but is there any way other than replacing it? Because F[a,b,c] is not my own function, but in an extra library written by others.